# Pyspark two DataFrame mapping on DataBricks

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark, databricks, databricks-sql

I am new to databricks(pyspark) and I want to map to dataframe-based on conditions. DF1 has id, date and some other columns and DF2 also has id, Date, and some other columns.
For example
DF1

| Date | name | ID | Other columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `21/06/2022` | ABC | XZ18610 |  |
| `22/05/2022` | ABC | XZ18610 |  |
| `22/04/2022` | ABC | XZ18610 |  |
| `05/05/2022` | DEF | XZ25277 |  |
| `04/02/2022` | DEF | XZ25277 |  |
| `28/06/2022` | GHI | XZU6S19 |  |
| `18/07/2022` | JKL | XZ54866 |  |
| `27/07/2022` | MNO | XZ82434 |  |
| `20/06/2022` | PQR | XZ78433 |  |

DF2

| Date1 | ID1 | Value | Other columns1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `30/05/2022` | XZ18610 | B |  |
| `21/06/2021` | XZ18610 | A |  |
| `05/01/2021` | XZ25277 | B |  |
| `28/07/2022` | XZU6S19 | E |  |
| `18/05/2022` | XZ54866 | D |  |
| `27/07/2022` | XZ82434 | F |  |
| `20/06/2022` | XZ78433 | I |  |

Desire output

| Date | name | ID | Other columns | Date1 | Value | Other columns1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `21/06/2022` | ABC | XZ18610 |  | `30/05/2022` | B |  |
| `22/05/2022` | ABC | XZ18610 |  | `21/06/2021` | A |  |
| `22/04/2022` | ABC | XZ18610 |  | `21/06/2021` | A |  |
| `05/05/2022` | DEF | XZ25277 |  | `05/01/2021` | B |  |
| `04/02/2022` | DEF | XZ25277 |  | `05/01/2021` | B |  |
| `28/06/2022` | GHI | XZU6S19 |  | `nan` | nan |  |
| `18/07/2022` | JKL | XZ54866 |  | `18/05/2022` | D |  |
| `27/07/2022` | MNO | XZ82434 |  | `27/07/2022` | F |  |
| `20/06/2022` | PQR | XZ78433 |  | `20/06/2022` | I |  |

Basically, I want to add other columns from DF2 to DF1 when ID is the same and DATE1 is less than DATE but is close to DATE. For example, if there are two DATE1 that are less than DATE then take the latest DATE1 and all other data from that row and add them to DF1.

I can do it in python with loops but my data are huge and it takes so much time so I wanted to do it in DataBricks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
    ('21/06/2022','ABC','XZ18610',''),
    ('22/05/2022','ABC','XZ18610',''),
    ('22/04/2022','ABC','XZ18610',''),
    ('05/05/2022','DEF','XZ25277',''),
    ('04/02/2022','DEF','XZ25277',''),
    ('28/06/2022','GHI','XZU6S19',''),
    ('18/07/2022','JKL','XZ54866',''),
    ('27/07/2022','MNO','XZ82434',''),
    ('20/06/2022','PQR','XZ78433','')
    ],
    ['Date','name','ID','Other columns']
)\
    .withColumn('Date', F.to_date('Date', 'd/M/y'))

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
    ('30/05/2022','XZ18610','B',''),
    ('21/06/2021','XZ18610','A',''),
    ('05/01/2021','XZ25277','B',''),
    ('28/07/2022','XZU6S19','E',''),
    ('18/05/2022','XZ54866','D',''),
    ('27/07/2022','XZ82434','F',''),
    ('20/06/2022','XZ78433','I','')
    ],
    ['Date1','ID1','Value','Other columns1']
)\
    .withColumn('Date1', F.to_date('Date1', 'd/M/y'))

                                                          
df3 = df1\
          .join(df2, df1.ID == df2.ID1, 'left')\
          .filter(df2.Date1 <= df1.Date)\
          .withColumn('datediff', F.datediff('Date', 'Date1'))\
          .withColumn("min", F.min('datediff').over(Window.partitionBy("Date", "ID")))\
          .filter(F.col('datediff')==F.col('min'))

result = df1.join(df3, ['Date', 'name', 'ID', 'Other columns'], 'left')
            
result\
        .select('Date','name','ID','Other columns','Date1','Value','Other columns1')\
        .show()


# +----------+----+-------+-------------+----------+-----+--------------+
# |      Date|name|     ID|Other columns|     Date1|Value|Other columns1|
# +----------+----+-------+-------------+----------+-----+--------------+
# |2022-06-21| ABC|XZ18610|             |2022-05-30|    B|              |
# |2022-05-22| ABC|XZ18610|             |2021-06-21|    A|              |
# |2022-04-22| ABC|XZ18610|             |2021-06-21|    A|              |
# |2022-05-05| DEF|XZ25277|             |2021-01-05|    B|              |
# |2022-02-04| DEF|XZ25277|             |2021-01-05|    B|              |
# |2022-06-28| GHI|XZU6S19|             |      null| null|          null|
# |2022-07-18| JKL|XZ54866|             |2022-05-18|    D|              |
# |2022-07-27| MNO|XZ82434|             |2022-07-27|    F|              |
# |2022-06-20| PQR|XZ78433|             |2022-06-20|    I|              |
# +----------+----+-------+-------------+----------+-----+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I try to refer my dataframe column by df.ID. It say "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ID'. But when I created dataframe as you created for sample it works fine.  But My dataframe is large and I can't create it like this.

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer. I can use the col function to get around that.

Comment: please mark as a solution if it works gor you